# I'm getting a blank screen when trying to connect Codeigniter to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter 1.7.2 on WAMP with php_pgsql and php_pdo_pgsql extensions enabled here is my configuration :

```
$active_group = "default";
$active_record = TRUE;
$db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['default']['username'] = "postgres";
$db['default']['password'] = "mypassword";
$db['default']['database'] = "mydatabasename";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "Postgre";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

when i open my application in a web browser all the existing urls return empty page when i view the source there is nothing 
What am i missing ?

Edit 
after cheking wamp log i found this :

> [Tue Jul 13 23:30:05 2010] [notice]
>   Parent: Created child process 4944 PHP
>   Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
>   dynamic library
>   'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0/ext/php_pgsql.dll'
>   - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0 
>   **Warning**:  PHP Startup: Unable
>   to load dynamic library
>   'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0/ext/php_pgsql.dll'
>   - The specified module could not be found.  in **Unknown** on line
>   **0**
>  [Tue Jul 13 23:30:05
>   2010] [notice] Child 4944: Child
>   process is running

any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Edit your php.ini, find postgre extension and enable it. Restart Apache, reload page and let us know again.

Comment: Well they are enabled but when apache start i get The specified module could not be found in the apache log ...

Comment: I bet it isn't called "postgre" but rather "postgres" or "postgresql"

Answer (score 1):

I think you must change `Postgre` to `postgres`, lowercase with a trailing s (per manual: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html).

There might be other problems.  Are interesting PHP errors in the Apache logs?

Comment: i posted some part of the apache log

Answer (score 1):

I'm running WAMP 2.2 on Windows 7 64 bit with POSTGRES 9.1, and adding the LoadFile line to httpd.conf cured the "blank page" syndrome with Codeigniter entirely:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
LoadFile "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/libpq.dll"
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
</VirtualHost>
```

Naturally, if you are not using Postgres 9.1, or your path to the .dll is different in some way, edit the LoadFile directive accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off pconnect and see if that works out.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway i installed WAPP and everything works fine now i think the php_pgsql.dll was not compatible with PHP 5.3

Answer (score 0):

Check if the DLL ("c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0/ext/php_pgsql.dll") referred in the apache error log really exists. If it does then look into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551734/php-not-loading-php-pgsql-dll-on-windows/552712#552712).

Answer (score 0):

enable `php_pgsql` extension from system tray => wamp icon => PHP => PHP Extensions => php_pgsql.

This solved my problem.