# Install Postgres for PHP on Windows 7 (64 bits)

Tags: php, postgresql, windows-7

I intalled correctly PostgreSQL and is running ok, as I can access the DB via the admin tool.

I'm trying to configure PHP 5.2.13 to load postgres extension, but failed so far, I don't get any information in PHP error log or Apache error log. So far I've done:

- Include PostgreSQL bin on windows path
- Copy php_pgsql.dll from my php/ext folder into system32 folder (also tryied other folders in the system path)
- Include the lines *extension=php_pgsql.dll* in ***php.ini*** and/or *LoadFile "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.0/bin/libpq.dll"* in ***httpd.conf***, both together and separately, all of the combinations resulting in Apache unable to restart without any log message.

I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551734/php-not-loading-php-pgsql-dll-on-windows) and others from php.net, but failed so char.

Any ideas or help?

Thank you

Comment: You don't have to (and cannot) load any pgsql dlls in Apache.

Comment: It could be useful to write the message of error. And to look at related questions (right panel of this page).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/551734/php-not-loading-php-pgsql-dll-on-windows/552712#552712

Comment: Milen, I already read that but don't really understand it, if I download a zipped version of PostrgreSQL all I see is this: _comerr64.dll, gssapi64.dll, k5sprt64.dll, krb5_64.dll, libeay32.dll, pgenlist.dll, pgenlista.dll, pgxalib.dll, psqlodbc30a.dll, psqlodbc35w.dll, ssleay32.dll_ no php_nothing.dll

Comment: php_pgsql.dll is a PHP extension, it's part of the PHP bundle for Windows. But it needs other DLLs (the ones you listed) to function correctly. Also it's a *good idea* to cite the error you recieve or what's not working and when.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php_pgsql.dll have to be in the ext folder of your PHP installation.
After you put the file there and enabled in in php.ini (the way you did) you have to restart the web server. After that you have to see PostreSQL extension in your phpinfo()

Comment: I'm doing that, included php/ext in path (just in case), but I'm not able to start apache when I try to load extension in php.ini, all message I have is this in apache error.log:

Comment: [Sat Jun 18 13:44:48 2011] [warn] pid file C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?

Comment: I don't think apache needs to load the pg library. Try reverting the httpd.conf and enabling pg extension only in php. Additionally, set the display_stratup_errors to 1 in php.ini, to see any errors while php tries to load the extension.

Comment: I'm only loading php extension, httpd.conf is in it's original state, but still no apache start. Thanks for yor help

Comment: I think you have problem with apache configuration, but try disabling the extension in php.ini as well to see if apache will be running. By the way, if you are using this as a development machine, you may be interested in installing wamp - it's really easy to enable and disable extensions there (it is a pre-configured package of apache,mysql and php with a control panel to manage your configuration)

Comment: Yes, if I comment _php_pgsql.dll_ extension in php.ini Apache is starting ok, so for sure the problem is there. I don't like wamp and that stuff, apache and mysql are installed in thise machine from a long time and no problem so far, do you think it will help in this case or I'll have problems with my previous installation of apacha/mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from PostgreSQL 9.3 and above Apache will not start with *libpq.dll* supplied with PostgreSQL. Instead in **httpd.conf** file of Apache set the path  to the *libpq.dll* of PHP catalog. In my case it is:

```
LoadFile "D:/PHP5.6.3/libpq.dll"
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to your steps above, try setting PHP extensions from within Wampserver by left clicking on Wampserver (green) icon -> PHP -> PHP Extensions -> click next to these extensions in the list (to check):

- pdo_pgsql
- pgsql

Here's my setup:

1. Windows 10,
2. Wampserver 3.1.9 (x64) which contains:

   - Apache 2.4.39,
   - PHP 7.3.7,
   - MySQL 5.7.24
3. PostgreSQL 11