# XAMPP + PostgreSQL = Errors

Tags: php, windows, apache, postgresql, xampp

I installed XAMPP and PostgreSQL on a Windows 7 machine.

I configured the apache httpd.conf and PHP.ini files just fine, and they work.
I uncommented the "extension php_pgsql.dll" line in the php.ini file and added \php, \php\ext, and the PostgreSQL \bin and \lib directories to my PATH variable.

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\lib;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin;C:\xampp\php\ext;C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP\php;C:\xampp\php;
```

I downloaded the php_pgsql.dll file that is compatible with windows and copied it to \php\ext

When I attempt to start the apache server, I get two errors:

> "The procedure entry point _regexec@20 could not be located in the dynamic link library php5ts.dll."

and

> "PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pgsql.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found."

So, these errors are obviously not fatal, meaning the server then continues to start and completes starting.
Also, if I comment out the "extension php_pgsql.dll" line in php.ini, the error disappears.
Here are the relevant error logs from PHP and apache:

Apache:

```
[Thu Nov 15 10:48:11.763770 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5420:tid 320] AH00455: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 15 10:48:11.763770 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5420:tid 320] AH00456: Server built: Aug 18 2012 12:41:37
[Thu Nov 15 10:48:11.763770 2012] [core:notice] [pid 5420:tid 320] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Nov 15 10:48:11.764770 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5420:tid 320] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5728
[Thu Nov 15 10:48:13.489869 2012] [ssl:warn] [pid 5728:tid 328] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Thu Nov 15 10:48:16.520042 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5728:tid 328] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

PHP:

```
[15-Nov-2012 15:48:11 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pgsql.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[15-Nov-2012 15:48:16 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pgsql.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0
```

I want to get this set up so I can write a PHP interface for a PostgeSQL database. This is just for fun, not in a professional context.

Comment: did you get the postgres module for windows-based php (e.g. php_pgsql.dll)?

Comment: Yea, I downloaded that and dropped it into the php\etc directory - that fixed the "not a valid win32 application" bug I was getting before.

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551734/php-not-loading-php-pgsql-dll-on-windows), i had this problem with `Windows 7 (64bit)`, i added the full path of `libpq.dll` from the `PostgreSQL` server installation path into `httpd.conf`, and the problem was solved.