# PGSQL not loaded in PHP 5.3 Windows under IIS

Tags: php, postgresql, iis, libpqxx

I know there are other questions about problems with PGSQL not loading, but I haven't found a solution that works for me and directly addresses an IIS setup under Windows (obviously). Using PostgreSQL 8.4.

Since I am a complete novice in PHP (only trying to get MantisBT to run) I find this extremely hard to debug/research.

I've set the path to both PostgreSQL bin folder and the PHP folders (v5.3 subfolder first and the PHP root after that). I've checked that libpq.dll is present in all three of these folders and I've tried copying the libpq.dll from the PostgreSQL folder to both PHP folders. I've made sure php.ini contains

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

in both PHP folders (root as well as v5.3).

What more to check/try/examine?

Comment: (1) Why have you chosen an old version of PostgreSQL? (2) Is it installed successfully and running - can you connect from psql/pg_admin(?)

Comment: Anything in the (event) logs? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/551734/php-not-loading-php-pgsql-dll-on-windows/

Comment: @Richard: I installed PostgreSQL over a year ago and I think I grabbed whatever was current at that time. Then I got swamped with other work and never got around to having a look at it until now. PostgreSQL seems to be working - I can connect with pgadmin, both to the server and to the MantisBT database, using the username and password I configured for MantisBT. But it's apparent that it fails in the call to init the DB connection in core.php (or whatever).

Comment: @Milen: Seems like the log file isn't flushed (C:\Windows\Temp\php53_errors.log). How do I flush it?

Comment: @Milan: OK, now I can at least see log entries that are dated after my trials earlier today. The log only contains a warning about zlib: ini_set(): Cannot change zlib.output_compression - headers already sent in C:\DataDIA\wwwroot\MantisBT\core\compress_api.php on line 68. Nothing about pgsql.

Comment: Executing php -m in the MantisBT root folder displays both pglib and pdo_pgsql, but MantisBT fails in database_api.php at line 82 where it calls db_check_database_support with the argument 'pgsql', which in turns calls function_exists('pg_connect'), which returns false.

Comment: @Kjell Rilbe - 8.4 was released in 2009 and will be end-of-life soon. Upgrade to something recent as soon as convenient. To see what is enabled/configured in php, put up a test page with a call to `phpinfo()`

Comment: @Richard: Will look into a PostgreSQL upgrade when I've got MantisBT up and running. I did try phpinfo() but it didn't give any apparent clues. What should I be looking for, apart from anything mentioning "pgsql" (which cannot be found anywhere).

Comment: If there's no "pg" related items in your phpinfo output then it's not loading the libraries. Check (1) the config file is being read and (2) the dll's are in the right place with the right permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried `phpinfo()` again, and it reports

```
Loaded Configuration File = C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.ini
```

which is correct and contains `extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll` and `extension=php_pgsql.dll`. As for "the dll's are in the right place" (@Richard), I have problems making sure exactly what dll:s are needed and where they should be located, but I have in `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\ext\` both `php_pdo_pgsql.dll` (version 5.3.12.0) and `php_pgsql.dll` (version 5.3.12.0).

I read about a dependency on `libpq.dll` and this is present in `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\`. Early in my "debugging" I copied the new `libpq.dll` (version 8.4.4.10133) from PostgreSQL to that folder, having read somewhere that it might solve the problem. I now tried reverting to the old version (8.3.6.9034) that shipped with PHP, and VOILA!!!! Suddenly `phpinfo()` says it has loaded both pdo and non-pdo pgsql modules.

MantisBT now loads the login screen at least. Whew!

Comment: I'm not quite certain why it din't work to begin with, but I suspect that it was in essence a path issue. I upgraded libpq.dll before adding path to PostgreSQL folder and v5.3 subfolder of PHP, and I think that's really the only change I made, that I haven't undone now.