# How can i install the php-pgsql on windows?

Tags: php, psql

whenever I initiate my localhost webpage, it returns me

> Call to undefined function pg_connect()

And i found out the am missing the `php-psql` on it. Now, how can i install it on windows as all the threads regarding that are on a Ubuntu environment.

Comment: Did you have a look on https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/ ? 
Download the installer and run it.

Comment: i do have the latest postgre/pgadmin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PGSQL not loaded in PHP 5.3 Windows under IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138373/pgsql-not-loaded-in-php-5-3-windows-under-iis)

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue where pdo_pgsql and pgsql were not loading in PHP 7.1.8 even though I had the latest PostgreSQL 9.4.6 and Apache 2.4.26 on Windows Server 2016.  The solution was pointing Apache's httpd.conf to the correct libpg.dll in PostgreSQL/bin folder.  Then the modules loaded correctly in PHP 7.

See [pgsql extension is not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675974/pgsql-extension-is-not-loading/45794103#45794103)