# pgsql extension is not loading

Tags: php, apache, postgresql

I am trying to use pgsql extension on Windows 10 64-bit (WAPP). 
I have:

- restarted Apache
- uncommented all postgresql extensions in `php.ini`
- used `LoadFile` to load `pgsql.dll`
- moved `pgsql.dll` to Apache bin (I tried both dll from php folder and from postgresql)

But still no result.
`pgsql` is visible only in `php.exe -m` but not in `phpinfo()`, `extension_loaded()`, `get_loaded_extensions()`.
My php version is `7.1.8` and PostgreSQL is `9.6` and Apache is `2.4.27`.
My `php.exe -m` output:
[image: php -m]

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SOLVED]

Okay, after a few hours of looking, I found the problem and was able to solve the problem with the pdo_pgsql and pgsql modules not showing in phpinfo().

[SOLUTION]

After uncommenting the extensions in php.ini, go into httpd.conf and add at the top of all the LoadModule lines the following:

LoadFile "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/libpq.dll"

(assuming you are using the latest version of PostgreSQL, otherwise change the number to the version you are using).

Save and restart Apache.  Go to phpinfo() and you will see it is loaded.

[REASON]

Apache is unable to see the libpg.dll even if you copy it into the Apache/bin folder.

[ENVIRONMENT]

- Windows Server 2016 (works for Windows 10 as well)
- Apache 2.4.26
- (x64) PHP 7.1.8 (x64 ThreadSafe VC14)
- PostgreSQL 9.6.4 (x64)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, command line PHP does not share the configuration file with Apache or in other words, the Apache `php.ini` is a different one then the one you edited.

Use `phpinfo()` running through apache and search for `php.ini` to locate the configuration file that was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution also works for the latest version of PHP 7, namely 7.3.5 on Windows 10 environment.

The inclusion of the LoadFile directive atop all the LoadModule directives simply works fine. I too was struggling for the solution. It appears that there is some issue on the said environment that the libpq.dll doesn't get loaded by default. The solution is awesome.

Comment: This is more like a comment to an existing answer than a new answer.