# php pdo_pgsql file present but not recognized

Tags: php, postgresql

Running a DigitalOcean droplet on Ubuntu (20.4?)

I have userA with root permission. They are also connected to userA within the postgres db.

Due to the setup for the software I'm using, they require a specific username for the postgresdb. Just so I'm not exposing too much data online, we'll call that userB. That's both a linux and postgres user.

I'm running a php command that basically takes (uname, dbname, pdo, options) as input, and it's currently failing bc it can't locate the pdo file.

I've looked through a few posts. One suggested to uncomment all of the pgsql and pdo_pgsql lines in all of the php.ini files, which i've done, both for production, development, and the generic version of that file.

When I run the command as both userA and userB I get this error.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_pgsql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_pgsql (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_pgsql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_pgsql.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_pgsql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params)) in Unknown on line 0
```

However, pdo_pgsql.so actually does exist in that location. (is it looking for a file just named pdo_pgsql and is instead finding pdo_pgsql.so?)

The php site says to run a

```
./configure
```

command, but it doesn't really say which folder configure is in. It's not a package I can install from cli. (https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.php)

Other pages say you have to install autoconf first (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158960/can-not-run-configure-command-no-such-file-or-directory) however that has not made ./configure an available command for me.

I've also found a post saying that a conf file in apache needs to be updated to show the location of the PDO file, however I'm not yet running a server, I'm just running a php file that populates a pgsql db locally. ([pgsql extension is not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675974/pgsql-extension-is-not-loading))

Running

```
php -i | grep PDO
```

gives

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_pgsql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_pgsql (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_pgsql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_pgsql.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_pgsql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params)) in Unknown on line 0
PDO
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => pgsql
PDO Driver for PostgreSQL => enabled
```

Though according to customer service from the API it should be returning

```
PDO
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql, odbc, pgsql
PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
PDO Driver for ODBC (unixODBC) => enabled
PDO Driver for PostgreSQL => enabled
```

Though I think they're giving multiple examples of different drivers depending on your db software of choice.

I'm not exactly sure what to do.

Update:

I've tried editing the php.ini file that is being used by php via

```
php -i | grep ini
```

I used

```
locate pdo_pgsql
```

to find the pdo_pgsql and pdo_pgsql.so filepaths. I have tried 4 different edits to the php.ini file. 2 being uncommenting (one at a time) the default pgsql extensions. 2 being different filepaths to the pdo_pgsql files that are found on my system through locate.

```
**extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_pgsql.so**

sudo php file.php

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_pgsql.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_pgsql.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_pgsql.so: **undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params**), /usr/lib/php/20190902//usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_pgsql.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902//usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_pgsql.so.so: **cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**)) in Unknown on line 0

**extension=/var/lib/php/modules/7.4/registry/pdo_pgsql**

sudo php file.php

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/var/lib/php/modules/7.4/registry/pdo_pgsql' (tried: /var/lib/php/modules/7.4/registry/pdo_pgsql (/var/lib/php/modules/7.4/registry/pdo_pgsql: **file too short**), /usr/lib/php/20190902//var/lib/php/modules/7.4/registry/pdo_pgsql.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902//var/lib/php/modules/7.4/registry/pdo_pgsql.so: **cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)**) in Unknown on line 0
Could not open input file: file.php

**extension=pgsql**

sudo php file.php

**PHP Warning:  Module 'pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0**
Could not open input file: file.php

**extension=pdo_pgsql**

sudo php file.php

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_pgsql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_pgsql (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_pgsql: **cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**), /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_pgsql.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_pgsql.so: **undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params**)) in Unknown on line 0
Could not open input file: file.php
```

output as requested by user below

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Mar  2 2022 15:36:52) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

$ dpkg -l|grep pgsql
ii  php-pgsql                       2:7.4+75                           all          PostgreSQL module for PHP [default]
ii  php7.4-pgsql                    7.4.3-4ubuntu2.10                  amd64        PostgreSQL module for PHP

$ dpkg -l|grep php
ii  php-common                      2:75                               all          Common files for PHP packages
ii  php-pgsql                       2:7.4+75                           all          PostgreSQL module for PHP [default]
ii  php7.4-cli                      7.4.3-4ubuntu2.10                  amd64        command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
ii  php7.4-common                   7.4.3-4ubuntu2.10                  amd64        documentation, examples and common module for PHP
ii  php7.4-json                     7.4.3-4ubuntu2.10                  amd64        JSON module for PHP
ii  php7.4-opcache                  7.4.3-4ubuntu2.10                  amd64        Zend OpCache module for PHP
ii  php7.4-pgsql                    7.4.3-4ubuntu2.10                  amd64        PostgreSQL module for PHP
ii  php7.4-readline                 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.10                  amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

If something does not work on your DEV enc, do not TRY it on the PROD.. this beats the purpose of having a DEV env..

in `php.ini` you should already have an example on how to enable pgsql:

```
extension=pdo_pgsql
```

not `module=`

I do not see what is your PHP version, but make sure you install the appropriate version of `php7.X-pgsql` as it seems you have the wrong version of the library..

You can maybe add to your question the output of:

```
dpkg -l|grep pgsql
dpkg -l|grep php
php -v
```

Comment: there was a typo in my question. I meant to write extention= not module=. I will fix that for future responders. php version is 7.4.3. both php and pgsql are 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.10