# Pgsql extension in Yii still "Warning" even after uncommenting "extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll" and "extension=php_pgsql.dll" in php.ini

Tags: php, postgresql, yii

I keep getting the error

```
CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver
```

even after uncommenting "extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll" and "extension=php_pgsql.dll and restarting wamp.

The Yii Requirement Checker still displays PDO PostgreSQL extension as "Warning".

Here's my code snippet

```
'db'=>array(
    'tablePrefix' => '',
    'connectionString' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=myDB',
    'username'=>'postgres',
    'password'=>'postgresql',
    'charset'=>'UTF8',
),
```

I'm using

Yii 1.1.14
Wamp 2.4
PHP 5.4.12

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/551734/php-not-loading-php-pgsql-dll-on-windows

Comment: An alternative explanation http://blog.lysender.com/2010/08/php-and-postgresql-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution somewhere, works for me

Assuming you have installed PostgreSQL and your WAMP installation is on c:\wamp, you will need to copy
c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\libpq.dll   to   c:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\bin

Make sure you also have the following files
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\ext\php_pdo_pgsql.dll   and
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\ext\php_pgsql.dll

Also, make sure you have enabled the above 2 files as extensions, either via the WAMP menu (click on WAMP icon on taskbar, PHP, PHPExtensions, find the above 2 and 'check' them)

Please note that php5.3.9 and Apache2.2.11 refer to my specific PHP and Apache versions.
Adjust those to suit your installation.

That's it!